# What does `{ buf -> ... }` mean in vim script?

Tags: vimscript

```
" As above, but curry the arguments so only the buffer number is required.
function! ale#VarFunc(variable_name) abort
    return {buf -> ale#Var(buf, a:variable_name)}
endfunction
```

What does `{ buf -> ... }` mean? It seems like a kind of function closure, but I can't find any document about this... :(

Comment: it is a lambda expression, see `:h lambda`

Comment: Oh, thanks man! You saved me! By the way, could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a lambda expression, see `:h lambda`.

The type of it is `v:t_func`.

It can be used where a Funcref is needed, see `:h Funcref`. For example, as the parameter of `map()` and `filter()`.